# GAM scaled t family for heavy tailed distributions

Tags: r, t-distribution, mgcv, heavy-tailed

I have some heavy tailed data I wish to model using the mgcv package in R with a t-distribution.

Reproducible example:

```
library(mgcv)
## Simulate some t data...
set.seed(3);n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
dat$y <- dat$f + rt(n,df=4)*2

b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=scat(link="identity"),data=dat)
```

This gives me an error message:

> Error in sprintf(format, ...) :    argument "format" is missing, with
>   no default

Could anybody please explain to me what is happening?

EDIT, output from devtools::session_info():

```
> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                                      
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)               
 os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu                          
 ui       RStudio                                    
 language (EN)                                       
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                                
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                                
 tz       Europe/Oslo                                
 date     2020-04-09                                 

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package          * version    date       lib source        
 assertthat         0.2.0      2017-04-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 backports          1.1.2      2017-12-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 base64enc          0.1-3      2015-07-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 bit                1.1-14     2018-05-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 bit64              0.9-7      2017-05-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 blob               1.1.1      2018-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 callr              3.3.0      2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 class              7.3-14     2015-08-30 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 classInt           0.2-3      2018-04-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 cli                1.1.0      2019-03-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 codetools          0.2-15     2016-10-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 colorspace         1.3-2      2016-12-14 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 crayon             1.3.4      2017-09-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 crosstalk          1.0.0      2016-12-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 data.table       * 1.12.6     2019-10-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 DataPrep           0.1.0      2020-03-12 [1] local         
 DBI                1.0.0      2018-05-02 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 desc               1.2.0      2018-05-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 devtools           2.2.1      2019-09-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 dichromat          2.0-0      2013-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 digest             0.6.15     2018-01-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 dplyr              0.8.3      2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 e1071              1.7-0      2018-07-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 ellipsis           0.3.0      2019-09-20 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 foreach            1.5.0      2018-08-01 [2] local         
 formatR            1.5        2017-04-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 fs                 1.3.1      2019-05-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 fst              * 0.8.8      2018-06-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 futile.logger    * 1.4.3      2016-07-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 futile.options     1.0.1      2018-04-20 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 gdalUtils          2.0.1.14   2018-04-23 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 GeneralFunctions   0.1.0      2020-03-12 [1] local         
 ggplot2          * 3.2.1      2019-08-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 glue               1.3.0      2018-07-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 gridExtra        * 2.3        2017-09-09 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 gtable             0.2.0      2016-02-26 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 hms                0.4.2      2018-03-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 htmltools          0.3.6      2017-04-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 htmlwidgets        1.2        2018-04-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 httpuv             1.4.5      2018-07-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 iterators          1.0.10     2018-08-01 [2] local         
 jsonlite           1.6        2018-12-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 KernSmooth         2.23-15    2015-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 labeling           0.3        2014-08-23 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 lambda.r           1.2.3      2018-05-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 later              0.7.3      2018-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 lattice            0.20-35    2017-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 lazyeval           0.2.1      2017-10-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 leaflet            2.0.1      2018-06-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 lwgeom             0.1-4      2018-01-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 magrittr           1.5        2014-11-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 mapview            2.4.0      2018-04-28 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Matrix             1.2-14     2018-04-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 memoise            1.1.0      2017-04-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 mgcv             * 1.8-30     2019-10-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 mime               0.5        2016-07-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 ModelBuild         0.1.0      2020-03-12 [1] local         
 munsell            0.5.0      2018-06-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 nlme             * 3.1-137    2018-04-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 odbc             * 1.1.6      2018-06-09 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pillar             1.4.2      2019-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgbuild           1.0.3      2019-03-20 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgconfig          2.0.1      2017-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 pkgload            1.0.2      2018-10-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 plyr               1.8.4      2016-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 png                0.1-7      2013-12-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 PreDataPrep        0.0.0.9000 2020-03-12 [1] local         
 prettyunits        1.0.2      2015-07-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 processx           3.4.0      2019-07-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 promises           1.1.0      2019-10-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 ps                 1.3.0      2018-12-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 purrr              0.2.5      2018-05-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R.methodsS3        1.7.1      2016-02-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R.oo               1.22.0     2018-04-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R.utils            2.6.0      2017-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R6                 2.4.1      2019-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 raster             2.6-7      2017-11-13 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 RColorBrewer       1.1-2      2014-12-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Rcpp               1.0.1      2019-03-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 remotes            2.1.0      2019-06-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 RevoUtils        * 11.0.1     2018-08-01 [2] local         
 RevoUtilsMath    * 11.0.0     2018-08-01 [2] local         
 rgdal              1.3-3      2018-06-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rgeos              0.3-28     2018-06-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rlang              0.4.0      2019-06-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rprojroot          1.3-2      2018-01-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rstudioapi         0.7        2017-09-07 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 satellite          1.0.1      2017-10-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 scales             0.5.0      2017-08-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sendmailR        * 1.2-1      2014-09-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sessioninfo        1.1.1      2018-11-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sf               * 0.6-3      2018-05-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 shiny              1.2.0      2018-11-02 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 sp                 1.3-1      2018-06-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 spData             0.2.9.0    2018-06-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 testthat           2.2.1      2019-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tibble             2.1.3      2019-06-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tidyselect         0.2.5      2018-10-11 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tmap             * 2.0        2018-07-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tmaptools          2.0        2018-07-14 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 units              0.6-0      2018-06-09 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 usethis            1.5.1      2019-07-04 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 viridisLite        0.3.0      2018-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 webshot            0.5.0      2017-11-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 withr              2.1.2      2018-03-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 XML                3.98-1.12  2018-07-15 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 xtable             1.8-2      2016-02-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 yaml               2.2.0      2018-07-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)

[1] /shared/home/G022602/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5
[2] /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/library
```

Comment: Hey I don't get any error running the code above. Do you have anything else loaded in your environment. I am on R 3.6.1 mgcv_1.8-31  nlme_3.1-145

Comment: Ah, so it is me =) I am an R newb, but it seems I have Microsoft R Open 3.5.1, mgcv_1.8-30 and nlme_3.1-137. I don't know what nlme is, but anyway... I appreciate you helping! Any idea what I could do?

Comment: It might help to post the output from `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` in your question as it could be some other package is loaded after *mgcv* that is masking some function in mgcv.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I have now included the output from session_info(). I apologize in advance if this was not how I should have included the output. I have seen some posts where dput has been used, so if this is preferred for you, let me know, and I can create  a github account and upload it there. Thanks again!